# How do we set database session variables in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

When using Hibernate and JPA, I have an existing DAO Abstract Class that sets up an entity manager this way:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "<name>")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

And in certain methods, it's used in the following manner:

```
public ObjectType findByPrimaryKey(int id) {
    return entityManager.find(ObjectType, id);
}
```

I wanted to set a database configuration parameter in the same transaction as the "find" query. However, I can't seem to find the internal transaction that entityManager uses. I wrote an Aspect that checks for Transactional annotation and sets the variable in there, and added @Transactional on top of findByPrimaryKey method, but that still didn't get set in the session.

Is there something incorrect here or another way to do it? Ideally, want to set a special variable before every query.

Comment: What exactly `database configuration parameter` you are trying to set?

Comment: It's in Postgres, under a custom namespace. Configuration parameter is supposed to be different per transaction. You can think of it as `mynamespace.user_id`. This is used in a policy on the table to filter out rows, for security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution was to combine Spring's "@Transactional" annotation, which automatically opens a transaction, before calling my Data access layer, with an Aspect that pointcuts to "@Transactional" annotation and runs queries within a transaction. Just executing any query within an "@Transactional" method will also work, before calling the Hibernate data access layer.

Without the "@Transactional" annotation, I couldn't control Hibernate's transaction management.